# Python "for" loop does not iterate as many as it should

Tags: python, loops

My python code does not iterate as many as it should. There are six image files in the working directory and len(f) also gives six. But the actual iteration of for loop stops after performing two loops.

```
import os
import cv2
import numpy as np

from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

path = "D:\\_my_python\\Image_histogram_equalization\\source_imgs"
os.chdir(path)
print("Current Working Directory: " , os.getcwd()) 

files = []
for r, d, f in os.walk(path):
    for file in f:
        if '.jpg' in file:
            files.append(os.path.join(r, file))

print("Processing %d files.." %len(f))
count = 0
for f in files:
    g = f[:f.find(".jpg")] + "_CLAHE20.jpg"
    print("Converting %s to %s..." % (f, g))
    img = cv2.imread(f)

    img_yuv = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2YUV)

    clahe = cv2.createCLAHE(clipLimit=2, tileGridSize=(8,8))
    img_yuv[:,:,0] = clahe.apply(img_yuv[:,:,0])

    img_output = cv2.cvtColor(img_yuv, cv2.COLOR_YUV2BGR)

    cv2.imwrite(g, img_output)
    count = count + 1
else:
    print("Process completed for %d files out of %d files. " % (count, len(f)))
```

It should run six loops because there are six images in the folder and len(f) also gives six.

Comment: I got it. It was because ".jpg" because some appear to be uppercase.

Comment: If you've found the answer to your question, please answer it in detail so that others can benefit as well. Specifically, you've bumped into the Windows weirdness that sometimes produces all-caps file extensions, because [Windows is case-insensitive](https://superuser.com/q/165975/684722)...

Comment: The path contained files which had filename extensions of uppercase ".JPG' and lowercase ".jpg" mixed together in a directory while my code considered the lowercase ".jpg" only. I solved it by considering both cases.